# How to find numbers inside strings (all inside a pandas df) with Python

Tags: python, pandas

[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvAi7.png)

I am trying to drop the numbers as strings inside of this pandas data frame. The problem is that I don't know of a way to locate them.

`df['Country'].unique()` returns the what is shown in the image above.
However, `'437.2' in df['Country']` returns `False`.

I would like to be able to create a list or set from 0-9, and search all strings in the column for numbers listed in the list/set, and finally drop the values where this condition is true.

Comment: Please provide an output of `print(your_sample_df)` instead of link to an image, along with what you have tried and expected output.

Comment: Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

`df[~df['Country'].str.contains("\d")]`

should give you what you want